# Return null instead of nothing if there are no results in kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

**Issue**

I have a kusto query which return no results. I want the query to return a single row consisting of null JUST when no rows are returned from the following query otherwise the query return the data.

**Example**

```
let Source = datatable(name:string, age:long)
[
  'John', 32,
  'Lisa', 24,
  'Lora', 55,
  'Adam', 66,
];
Source 
| where age <= 20
| project name, age
```

**Expected result**

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Name        |        Age       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Null        |        Null      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could `union` with a `datatable` that has a record with an empty string and a `null`, as follows:

```
let Source = datatable(name:string, age:long)
[
  'John', 32,
  'Lisa', 24,
  'Lora', 55,
  'Adam', 66,
];
let T = Source 
| where age <= 20
| project name, age
;
let T_has_records = toscalar(T | summarize count() > 0);
union 
(T | where T_has_records == true),
(datatable(name:string, age:long)['', long(null)] | where T_has_records == false)
```

Comment: Hi Yoni, the query is correct but union operation make the query takes long time to execute. is there another idea to make this done

Comment: Only one of the union legs is evaluated in the example, as they have opposite filters on the same boolean value. the added overhead is counting the records in the table, to evaluate that boolean